# Powershell - Matches [1] don't work with "|"

Tags: windows, powershell

1

This is part of the code I created:

```
$NameOrigin = "BP |"
$NameBackup = "Backup"
Get-CimInstance win32_logicaldisk |
 ForEach-Object{
     if ($_.VolumeName -match "^$NameOrigin(.+)" -and $_.VolumeName -notmatch "^$NameBackup(.+)" ){
         $Employee = $Matches[1]
         $FSRootOrigin = "{0}{1}" -f $_.DeviceId,'\'
     }
 }
```

Basically it checks if there is any drive with the word `"BP |"` and that does not contain the word `"Backup"` in the volume label and gets the letter of that drive.

Given that, if you look at the $Employee variable, the idea is that it extracts what is after `"|"` so I can use it in another step of the script, however for some reason it doesn't work when the drive is named using `"|"`.

When the `$NameOrigin` variable was `"BP -"` I was able to extract the information that was after the `"-"`.

Why doesn't it work using `"|"`?

How can I get around this?

Comment: "|" is a regex symbol meaning "or".  You can backslash it.

Comment: Ahh right, so how do I mention a unit that has "|" on the volume label and ask to extract what's after the "|"?

Comment: depends on how much youre trying to extract. You have a before and after of what youre trying to accomplish?

Comment: Group the stuff after?  `\|(.*)` and look in $matches[1].  Is this in the question?

Comment: Basically every storage unit follows the rule "BP | 'Employee Name'"

So I need to extract everything after "|" so that I can get the employee's name to use in a robocopy command later on.

Comment: @js2010 I just needed to remove `(.*)` and your solution worked perfectly!

With `(.*)` for some reason generates more strings and only extract a part of the name.

Thank you very much for your attention and patience!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess the answer is to escape the pipe because it's regex for "or".

```
$NameOrigin = "BP \|"
```

Comment: Thanks.  I just got to 20,000.